# C++ detect templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

```
template<typename T>
struct check
{
  static const bool value = false;
};
```

What I want to do is to have `check<T>::value` be true if and only if `T` is a `std::map<A,B>` or `std::unordered_map<A,B>` and both `A` and `B` be `std::string`. So basically `check` enables compile-time checking of the type `T`.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Partial specialization for when you want to allow any comparator, hasher, key-equal-comparator and allocator:

```
template<class Comp, class Alloc>
struct check<std::map<std::string, std::string, Comp, Alloc>>{
  static const bool value = true;
};

template<class Hash, class KeyEq, class Alloc>
struct check<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string, Hash, KeyEq, Alloc>>{
  static const bool value = true;
};
```

If you want to check if `T` used the default version of those types (aka only `map<A,B>` and not `map<A,B,my_comp>`, you can omit the template arguments and go with explicit specialization:

```
template<>
struct check<std::map<std::string, std::string>>{
  static const bool value = true;
};

template<>
struct check<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>>{
  static const bool value = true;
};
```

And if you want to generally check if it's a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` of any key/value combination (and comparator / hasher / etc.), you can go fully generic as taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11251376/500104):

```
#include <type_traits>

template < template <typename...> class Template, typename T >
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type {};

template < template <typename...> class Template, typename... Args >
struct is_specialization_of< Template, Template<Args...> > : std::true_type {};

template<class A, class B>
struct or_ : std::integral_constant<bool, A::value || B::value>{};

template<class T>
struct check
  : or_<is_specialization_of<std::map, T>,
       is_specialization_of<std::unordered_map, T>>{};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use some partial template specialization

```
// no type passes the check
template< typename T >
struct check
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

// unless is a map
template< typename Compare, typename Allocator >
struct check< std::map< std::string, std::string, Compare, Allocator > >
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

// or an unordered map
template< typename Hash, typename KeyEqual, typename Allocator >
struct check< std::unordered_map< std::string, std::string, Hash, KeyEqual, Allocator > >
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
```