# Doing a static_assert that a template type is another template

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++11

How do I `static_assert` like this? Maybe Boost supports it if not C++ or new features in C++11?

```
template<T>
struct foo {};

template<FooType>
struct bar {
  static_assert(FooType is indeed foo<T> for some T,"failure"); //how?
};
```

Comment: A related question can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919310/c-detect-templated-class/12919396)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could do something along these lines. Given a trait that can verify whether a class is an instantiation of a class template:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, template<typename> class TT>
struct is_instantiation_of : std::false_type { };

template<typename T, template<typename> class TT>
struct is_instantiation_of<TT<T>, TT> : std::true_type { };
```

Use it as follows in your program:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {};

template<typename FooType>
struct bar {
  static_assert(is_instantiation_of<FooType, foo>::value, "failure");
};

int main()
{
    bar<int> b; // ERROR!
    bar<foo<int>> b; // OK!
}
```

If you want, you could generalize this to detect whether a class is an instance of a template with any number of (type) parameters, like so:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<template<typename...> class TT, typename T>
struct is_instantiation_of : std::false_type { };

template<template<typename...> class TT, typename... Ts>
struct is_instantiation_of<TT, TT<Ts...>> : std::true_type { };

template<typename FooType>
struct bar {
  static_assert(is_instantiation_of<foo, FooType>::value, "failure");
};
```

You would then use it this way in your program:

```
template<typename FooType>
struct bar {
  static_assert(is_instantiation_of<foo, FooType>::value, "failure");
};

int main()
{
    bar<int> b; // ERROR!
    bar<foo<int>> b; // OK!
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=bd92515881e87149e3ca436c493d8609-a63ad9fea3739cb794a74965e5d28fb3).

Comment: Do you (or others here) think that the knowledge from reading the book "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide" by Vandevoorde and Josuttis would have allowed me to do this on my own?

Comment: Hmm, probably not, since `std::true_type` is a C++11 feature :( There don't seem to be any new template books around for C++11.

Comment: @roger.james: That is a good book and I advise reading it anyway. However, as you mentioned, in this answer I used C++11 features that are not presented in that book (especially variadic templates).

Comment: Is it possible to generalize it even further to make type aliases succeed? Example of how it currently fails: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d318fcac90651bcffa5e

Comment: There are two options here: 1) All aliases are equivalent to each other. 2) If the original uses foo_alt, only foo_alt (and not foo) will succeed in the static_assert, and vice versa. Can both versions be accomplished?

Comment: @roger.james: First of all, this is an unrelated question :) Please post a new question and accept this answer if it answers the question you posted. Secondly, I think the problem here is that `foo_alt` is *not* a class template, it is a template alias. I am actually surprised that it can be used as a template *template-argument*. (continues...)

Comment: @roger.james: In [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=529ded1ad759c6854f6ccef85f6afab2-a63ad9fea3739cb794a74965e5d28fb3), for instance, you can see how the static assert fires even if the input type is an instantiation of `foo_alt`, while the assertion `static_assert(is_instantiation_of<foo,FooType>::value, "failure")` does not fire even if the type is an instantiation of `foo_alt` (because `foo_alt` is basically an alias for `foo`).

Comment: I have accepted the answer and posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392621/using-a-template-alias-instead-of-a-template-within-a-template

Comment: Would it be hard to extend this such that *subclasses* of `foo<whatever>` would also be allowed?

Comment: @roger.james: I guess it could be done, yes, but I would have to try and play with it a bit in order to be sure. Anyway, sounds like another good question for SO ;)

Comment: I created a new question again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395714/extending-this-template-static-assert-code-to-cover-subclasses

Comment: By the way, the live example is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Some small improvements over the other answers:

- the name actually makes sense regarding the order of the parameters
- handles `const`, `volatile`, and reference types properly via std::decay
- implements C++14-style _v `constexpr` variable
- accepts an arbitrary number of types to test against (tests for ALL)

I have intentionally not put the std::decay_t on the is_template_for_v because a type trait should work identically regardless of whether it is called with the _v suffix or not.

This does require C++17 for `std::conjunction`, but you can either remove the variadic feature or implement your own `conjunction` using c++11/14.

```
template<template<class...> class tmpl, typename T>
struct _is_template_for : public std::false_type {};

template<template<class...> class tmpl, class... Args>
struct _is_template_for<tmpl, tmpl<Args...>> : public std::true_type {};

template<template<class...> class tmpl, typename... Ts>
using is_template_for = std::conjunction<_is_template_for<tmpl, std::decay_t<Ts>>...>;

template<template<class...> class tmpl, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool is_template_for_v = is_template_for<tmpl, Ts...>::value;
```

Usage:

```
static_assert(is_template_for_v<std::vector, std::vector<int>>); // doesn't fire
```

Answer (score -2):

As someone else wrote,

```
template<typename T, template<typename...> class TT>
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type { };

template<template<typename...> class TT, typename... Ts>
struct is_specialization_of<TT<Ts...>, TT> : std::true_type { };
```

However, beware that this works only for template classes *whose template parameters are all typenames!* Presented with

```
typedef std::array<int, 42> MyArray;
static_assert(is_specialization_of<MyArray, std::array>::value, "");
```

it will simply fail to compile at all.

I believe C++11/C++14/C++17 currently have no way to deal with this limitation.

Comment: This is not an answer.  Copy/pasting someone else's answer and then commenting on it is not an appropriate answer.  If you have a comment on someone's answer, leave a comment on their answer.

Comment: Who is "someone else"? Please update this answer to provide proper [attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) to whomever you've copied this code from. Was it [Xeo's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12919396), or another answer?

Comment: Welcome to 2017, you two! :)  Feel free to edit "someone else" to "Andy Prowl" if you feel like it.