# Using a template alias instead of a template within a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

From a previous question:

[Doing a static_assert that a template type is another template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390605/doing-a-static-assert-that-a-template-type-is-another-template)

Andy Prowl provided me with this code that allows me to `static_assert` that a template type is another template type:

```
template<template<typename...> class TT, typename... Ts>
struct is_instantiation_of : public std::false_type { };

template<template<typename...> class TT, typename... Ts>
struct is_instantiation_of<TT, TT<Ts...>> : public std::true_type { };

template<typename T>
struct foo {};

template<typename FooType>
struct bar {
  static_assert(is_instantiation_of<foo,FooType>::value, ""); //success
};

int main(int,char**)
{
  bar<foo<int>> b; //success
  return 0;
}
```

This works great.

But if I change the code like this to use an alias of `foo`, things go bad:

```
template<template<typename...> class TT, typename... Ts>
struct is_instantiation_of : public std::false_type { };

template<template<typename...> class TT, typename... Ts>
struct is_instantiation_of<TT, TT<Ts...>> : public std::true_type { };

template<typename T>
struct foo {};

//Added: alias for foo
template<typename T>
using foo_alt = foo<T>;

template<typename FooType>
struct bar {
  //Changed: want to use foo_alt instead of foo here
  static_assert(is_instantiation_of<foo_alt,FooType>::value, ""); //fail
};

int main(int,char**) {
  //both of these fail:
  bar<foo<int>> b;
  bar<foo_alt<int>> b2;

  return 0;
}
```

Can this be solved?

Comment: Hmm, looks like `foo_alt` is a *typedef-name* and not a *template-name*... but that only affects your `bar`; you can keep `main` as it is.

Comment: I think you could check if two types are instantiations of the same template, this also works with alias templates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it cannot be solved (not without changing the design significantly at least). The problem is that template alias names are not deduced, as mentioned in paragraph 14.5.7/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> When a template-id refers to the specialization of an alias template, it is equivalent to the associated type
>   obtained by substitution of its template-arguments for the template-parameters in the type-id of the alias
>   template. [ **Note: An alias template name is never deduced.—end note** ]

The paragraph also provides an example:

> [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct Alloc { / ... / };
> template<class T> using Vec = vector<T, Alloc<T>>;
> Vec<int> v; // same as vector<int, Alloc<int>> v;
>
> ...
>
> template<template<class> class TT>
> void f(TT<int>);
> f(v); // error: Vec not deduced                          <=== Relevant
>
> ...
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

In your concrete case, the problem is that when trying to match the partial specialization, the compiler won't deduce that your type is an instantiation of `foo_alt` (since `foo_alt` is the name of an alias template), and the primary template gets picked.

If you want to use alias templates, you will have to give up a bit of genericity and create a type trait specific for `foo`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct foo {};

template<typename T>
struct is_instantiation_of_foo : std::false_type { };

template<typename...Ts>
struct is_instantiation_of_foo<foo<Ts...>> : std::true_type { };
```

Which you could then use this way:

```
template<typename FooType>
struct bar {
  static_assert(is_instantiation_of_foo<FooType>::value, ""); //fail
};
```

Now, none of the assertions in the following program will fire:

```
template<typename T>
using foo_alt = foo<T>;

int main(int,char**) {
  // None of these fail:
  bar<foo<int>> b;
  bar<foo_alt<int>> b2;

  return 0;
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8eaa698f73db8c4fdab23a2f86ab3aaf-a63ad9fea3739cb794a74965e5d28fb3).

Comment: Maybe we can do better.  `SFINAE`-safe pattern match deduce the `template` `M` such that the passed in type is `M<Ts...>` for some `Ts...`.  Then check `std::is_same<X<Ts...>,M<Ts...>>`, also SFINAE guarded in case that `X<Ts...>` is ill formed, where `X<>` is the `template` passed in to match...

Comment: @Yakk: You're too genius for me :) I don't understand what "SFINAE-deduce` means, and I'm afraid I would need to stare at the solution a few minutes before I get it anyway ;)

Comment: see dyn's answer: I was less than clear, and writing code on this keyboard is hard.  I meant "deduce in a SFINAE safe way", so if it failed to match it would just say `false`.  Dyn spotted the flaw I missed: he's too smart for me!

Comment: @Yakk No he's not too smart, but he's got a P at the end ;)

Comment: @Yakk You were right that some guard is required to check if `X<Ts...>` is ill-formed. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an alias template that does **not** alter the template parameters of the referred class (like in your example; it just renames the referred template), then you can use something like (it's not the most elegant way)

```
template < template<class...> class TT0, template<class...> class TT1,
           class... Ts1 >
struct is_from_same_template_helper
{
    template < class T = TT0<Ts1...>,
               class = typename std::enable_if<
                   std::is_same<TT0<Ts1...>, TT1<Ts1...>>::value
               >::type
             >
    static std::true_type test(int);

    template < class T = int >
    static std::false_type test(...);
};


template<template<class...> class, class>
struct is_instantiation_of : public std::false_type { };

template<template<class...> class TT0, template<class...> class TT1,
         class... Ts1>
struct is_instantiation_of<TT0, TT1<Ts1...>>
    : public decltype( is_from_same_template_helper<TT0, TT1, Ts1...>
                       ::template test<>(0) )
{ };
```

Thanks to [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk) for pointing out that you need a SFINAE-type of check in order to only let the `static_assert` fail (previous version failed due to a compiler error before the `static_assert`).

As only the specializations of alias templates are equal to specializations of the referred template; the alias template itself is not equal to the referred template.

**If the alias template does alter the template parameters, the implementation above can create false negatives.**

---

As an xy-Problem, you could change your implementation to:

```
#include <type_traits>


template < template <typename...> class TT0, template <typename...> class TT1 >
struct is_same_template : public std::false_type { };

template < template <typename...> class TT >
struct is_same_template < TT, TT > : public std::true_type { };


template < typename T0, typename T1 >
struct is_from_same_template : public std::false_type { };

template < template <typename...> class TT0, template <typename...> class TT1,
           typename... Ts0, typename... Ts1 >
struct is_from_same_template < TT0<Ts0...>, TT1<Ts1...> >
    : public is_same_template<TT0, TT1> { };


template<typename T>
struct foo {};

//Added: alias for foo
template<typename T>
using foo_alt = foo<T>;

template<typename FooType>
struct bar {
  //Changed: want to use foo_alt instead of foo here
  static_assert(is_from_same_template<foo_alt<int>, FooType>::value, "");
};

int main(int,char**) {
  //both of these succeed:
  bar<foo<int>> b;
  bar<foo_alt<int>> b2;

  return 0;
}
```

Of course, you need to have a valid instantiation of `foo_alt` for this approach.

Comment: I can't understand what is the purpose of `TT1` template parameter of `is_from_same_template_helper` template.

Comment: @Constructor As I "announced" in my previous comment here, there's been a bug in the code (introduced according to the edit history when changing from hard to SFINAE error). Is it clear now?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice your comment. It is clear now, thank you. As I see you can't decide which keyword you like more (`typename` or `class`). :-)