# Does template specialization work with alias templates?

Tags: templates, c++11

Does template specialization work with alias templates?  Specifically, the following code throws an unexpected error:

```
$ cat test01.h 
#ifndef TEST01_H
#define TEST01_H

#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstdlib>

template <template <typename> class Ops>
double add1(double const & x) {
    std::cerr << "Undefined for type: " << typeid(Ops <double>).name() << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

template <typename Real>
struct MyOps {
    static Real add(Real const & x,Real const & y) {
        return x+y;
    }
};

template <typename Real> using MyOpsAlias = MyOps <Real>;

#endif
```

In addition,

```
$ cat test01.cpp 
#include "test01.h"

template <>
double add1 <MyOps> (double const & x) {
    return MyOps <double>::add(x,1.);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << add1 <MyOps> (2.) << std::endl;
    std::cout << add1 <MyOpsAlias> (2.) << std::endl;
}
```

After running this code, I receive

```
$ ./test01 
3
Undefined for type: 5MyOpsIdE
```

I expected that both answers should return 3 since MyOpsAlias should just be an alias template of MyOps.  In case it matters, I'm using GCC 4.7.3.

Comment: Perhaps you might be interested in [my recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892052/strange-behaviour-of-is-same-template-on-template-aliases).

Comment: Interesting. That means that gcc typeid's implementation doesn't take care of template aliases. The standard doesn't say how typeid should work (implementation defined).

Comment: you should report the bug to gcc

Comment: @BЈовић It is not a bug, it is a standard-compliant behavior. See the reference above.

Comment: @Constructor Thanks. in that case this question is a duplicate of that question

Comment: @Constructor I think you're correct.  If you copy that comment into an answer, I'll accept it and close this out.

Comment: @wyer33 [Done.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23298947/3043539)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [**Johannes Schaub - litb**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb) explains in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22896036/3043539) to [my recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22892052/3043539):

> A alias template is *not* a template alias (despite intended by some to be).

So it is not a bug, it is a standard-compliant behavior.

See also paragraph [temp.alias] 14.5.7/2 of the standard:

> *[ Note:* An alias template name is never deduced. *— end note ]*

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following:

```
namespace detail
{

template <typename T> struct Adder
{
    double operator() (double) const {
        std::cerr << "Undefined for type: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
};

template <typename T> struct Adder<MyOps<T>>
{
    double operator() (double x) const {
        return MyOps<T>::add(x, 1.);
    }
};

}

template <template <typename> class T>
double add1(double const & x) {
    return detail::Adder<T<double>>()(x);
}
```

Comment: There are a few errors in your code: `template <template T> struct Adder<MyOps<T>>`, `double operator() (double) const` and `detail::Adder<T<double>>()(x);`.