# Identity of template aliases

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, standards, template-aliases

Let's consider a set of template aliases:

```
template<class T> using foo = T*;
template<class T> using bar = T*;
template<class T> using buz = foo<T>;

template< template<class>class TT > struct id {};

using id_foo = id<foo>;
using id_bar = id<bar>;
using id_buz = id<buz>;
```

Are `id_foo`, `id_bar`, `id_buz` same or different types? Are `foo`, `bar`, `buz` same or different templates?

Various compilers have different opinions on that.
Particularly,

- MSVC 2015 and clang 3.5 treat they all are different
- gcc 4.9 treats `buz` is same as `foo`

Standard C++11 in the chapter 14.5.7 "Alias templates" is unclear.

Comment: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)'s explanation seems to imply that yes, they are the same IMO. Edit: Relevant snippet: `An alias template is a template which, when specialized, is equivalent to the result of substituting the template arguments of the alias template for the template parameters in the type-id`

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1286

Comment: Answers to the following questions may be helpful: [_Using a template alias instead of a template within a template_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392621/3043539) and [_Strange behaviour of is_same_template on template aliases_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22892052/3043539).

Comment: @T.C. Other than it being only a link, how is that not an answer?  :p

Answer (score 1):

As [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) pointed out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080574/identity-of-template-aliases#comment46396030_29080574) to the question, this is a [known hole](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1286) of the standard.

> The current wording of 14.5.7 [temp.alias] deals only with the equivalence of a specialization of an alias template with the type-id after substitution. Wording needs to be added specifying under what circumstances an alias template itself is equivalent to a class template.

That is: any specialization of `foo`, `bar` and `buz` will represent the same type. But there is no guarantee that, when used as a template parameter, `foo`, `bar` and `buz` are interchangeable.