# Is this a bug, or a C++ language feature

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

The following code works fine:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename> class AddLayer;

template <template <typename> class TLayer>
struct LayerInputPortSet
{
    using type = int;
};

template <>
struct LayerInputPortSet<AddLayer>
{
    using type = float;
};

using type = typename LayerInputPortSet<AddLayer>::type;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<type, float>);
```

But with the following modification:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename> class AddLayer;

template <template <typename> class TLayer>
struct LayerInputPortSet
{
    using type = int;
};

template <>
struct LayerInputPortSet<AddLayer>
{
    using type = float;
};

template <template<typename> class TLayer>
struct Sublayer
{
    template <typename TInputs>
    using LayerType = TLayer<TInputs>;
};

using type = typename LayerInputPortSet<Sublayer<AddLayer>::template LayerType>::type;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<type, float>);
```

As I understand, since "A type alias declaration introduces a name which can be used as a synonym for the type denoted by type-id", therefore `Sublayer<AddLayer>::template LayerType` is an alias of `AddLayer`, so `type` should be `float` based on the template specialization.

This code works on GCC, but it cannot be compiled on clang 6, clang 7, clang 8, and VS 2019. In fact, if I change the last line as:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same_v<type, int>);
```

The code could be compiled on clang 6, clang 7, clang 8, and VS 2019.

I don't know which compiler's behavior is correct: GCC or Clang/VS ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [It also compiles ins gbd](https://onlinegdb.com/B1yrsmhuS), but I couldn't tell you which is correct.

Comment: I prefer [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/lpZ5Am) @Chipster

Comment: In fact, there is a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392621/using-a-template-alias-instead-of-a-template-within-a-template). One answer about that question is "An alias template name is never deduced." But I don't think this answer is correct. Since there is no argument deduction involved inside the code.