# Running code if a template type is another template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

How can I do this in C++? The lack of `static_if` will make it harder.

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
  foo() {
    //construction

    //if (T is an instantiation of some other template, say std::vector)
    //{
    //   stuff 1
    //}
  }

  void some_func() {
    //some code

    //if (T is an instantiation of some other template, say std::vector)
    //{
    //   stuff 2
    //}
  }
};
```

If it's any help, here's code that tells us whether `T` is another template:

[Doing a static_assert that a template type is another template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390605/doing-a-static-assert-that-a-template-type-is-another-template)

The only question is how to translate it into an "if" condition.

Comment: take a look at type traits and how thei are implemented (nothing obscure), and after that you will be able to make your "static_if"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dispatch helper functions:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
public:
  foo() {
    //construction

    stuff1(static_cast<T*>(nullptr));
  }

  void some_func() {
    //some code

    stuff2(static_cast<T*>(nullptr));    
  }

private:
  template<typename U> void stuff1(U*) {}
  template<typename E, typename A> void stuff1(std::vector<E,A>*)
  { /* stuff 1 */ }

  template<typename U> void stuff2(U*) {}
  template<typename E, typename A> void stuff2(std::vector<E,A>*)
  { /* stuff 2 */ }
};
```

Comment: That's quite genius, what's the need for `static_if` then (many seem to want it in C++)? Your solution seems to cover a lot of ground!

Comment: `static_if` would make this sort of thing easier and allow you to keep all the logic in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

The link you point to already has an condition code that tells you the right answer. All you have to do is put it inside an "if".

There is no need for a "static_if". If your code can determine, at compile time, whether an if is taken or not, the not-taken path is optimized out, as well as the actual if statement. Since a template function is instantiated (read - compiled) for each type individually, and since for each of those instantiations the if condition can be statically detected, just use the standard if.

Shachar

Comment: This won't work if the `if` block contains code that would be ill-formed for some template specializations - for example, it uses members of `vector` which might not exist on a general `T`.