# Variadic template of variadic template class

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

I am trying to create a function named `Choose` which can take the following as arguments:

```
template<typename... Args>
class Option
{
    Option(Args... arguments)
    {
        // irrelevant
    }
    // ...
}

void Foo()
{
    Choose(
         Option<int, int>(3, 5),
         Option<int>(7,123),
         Option<int, int, int, int>(1, 2, 3, 4)
    );
}
```

So I have a class with variadic types, and I want to create a function that takes any number of instances of that class, of which every instance can have `different` arguments for its types.

I was able to create such a function, where all instances need to have the same arguments for their types:

```
template <template <typename... Args> class... Opt, typename... Args>
void Choose(EnemyAIState& state, Opt<Args...>... option)
{
    // irrelevant
}

void Foo()
{
    Choose(state,
        Option<int>(1),
        Option<int>(2),
        Option<int>(3)
    );
}
```

However, I am unable to achieve my final goal, as I cannot find the right `syntax` to use. I am hoping you can help me in the right direction.

Comment: You can always take them as simply `template<typename...Opt> void Choose(EnemyAIState& state, Opt... option)`.

Comment: Oh wow haha, fresh thoughts are always better. Now that it works, I'm still interested in if this is possible at all.

Comment: By which I mean in the way I started it.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. If you want better error messages, use a `static_assert`.

Comment: @AartStuurman: Answers do NOT go in questions.  If your "answer" is different than T.C.'s answer, post that as a new answer on this page please.

Comment: If your answer is merely an _extension_ of his, you could alternatively post a link to the code in a comment on his answer and suggest that he update his answer.  But posting it as a new answer is still acceptable.

Comment: I've removed the code from my question, and posted a link to the question where a already clear explanation was given for it, instead, at T.C.s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you are trying to do directly - you'd need something like a "pack of packs", and there's no such thing.

If you want better error messages, write a `static_assert` that tests that each of the types passed in is an `Option`:

```
// helper template that checks all of values are true
template<bool... values>
struct all_true;

template<>
struct all_true<> : std::true_type { };

template<bool b, bool...values>
struct all_true<b, values...> : std::integral_constant<bool, b && all_true<values...>::value> { };

template<typename... Args>
struct Option
{
    Option(Args... /*arguments*/)
    {
        // irrelevant
    }
    // ...
};

// trait class that tests that a type is an Option
template<typename T>
struct is_option : std::false_type { };

template<typename... Args>
struct is_option<Option<Args...>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename... Opt>
void Choose(Opt... arguments)
{
    // check that each type is an Option
    static_assert(all_true<is_option<Opt>::value...>::value, "Arguments must all be Options");
    // irrelevant
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1484db3476e0c1a).

Comment: That's pretty cool. I didn't know about assertion in C++ at all. Thanks a lot, this gives some clear messages.

Comment: The following link provides a generic version of your is_option function, which might be useful for people reading this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390605/doing-a-static-assert-that-a-template-type-is-another-template.

Answer (score 1):

If processing the parameters one at a time, the standard variadic template solution works well:

```
void Choose()
{
    //do nothing, end of list
}

template <typename... Args, class... Rest>
void Choose(const Option<Args...>& option, Rest&&... rest)
{
    //irrelevant

    Choose(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
}
```

It gives the same error message you'd get the other way, just in a more intimidating callstack size.  This is how most variadic template functions work that I've seen: quasi-recursion.

http://ideone.com/XuWSSx