# Trying to disable a function if any type of list is passed in

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I am trying to disable a function if any type of a list class is passed into the function with the following enable_if

```
template <typename ContainerType, typename KeyType,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<
            std::decay_t<ContainerType>,
            std::list<typename ContainerType::value_type>>::value>>
void func(ContainerType&& container, KeyType&& key)
```

But when I call func with  `vector<int>` I get the error

```
candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with ContainerType = std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > &, KeyType = int]: type 'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > &' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no
  members
```

A vector does have the member typedef `value_type` to get the value of the thing stored in it..

Any idea how I can go about fixing this?

Comment: `std::enable_if` should possibly be `std::enable_if_t`?

Comment: @StoryTeller Good eye!  But that did not fix the error :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The direct problem is here:

```
std::list<typename ContainerType::value_type>>::value>>
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In your example, `ContainerType` is a reference type (`std::vector<int>&`) and you can't access typedefs off of a reference type. You'd have to remove the reference first.

But we can do it simpler by just ignoring the `KeyType` part:

```
template <class X> struct is_list : std::false_type { };
template <class T, class A> struct is_list<std::list<T,A>> : std::true_type { };

template <class Container, class Key,
    std::enable_if_t<!is_list<std::decay_t<Container>>::value>* = nullptr>
void func(ContainerType&&, Key&& ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 5):

Basing my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390605/doing-a-static-assert-that-a-template-type-is-another-template) SO post. A better approach will be as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<template<typename...> class TT, typename T>
struct is_instantiation_of : std::false_type { };

template<template<typename...> class TT, typename... Ts>
struct is_instantiation_of<TT, TT<Ts...>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename ContainerType, typename KeyType,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<!is_instantiation_of<
            std::list, std::decay_t<ContainerType>>::value>>
void func(ContainerType&& container, KeyType&& key)
```

The main strength of this is that faffing around with the rest of `std::list`s type parameters will not allow to bypass your check.

Comment: I would accept this answer but the one above addresses why I had the error as well so I am going to go for that one, I upvoted this though. Thanks!