# C++ Concepts: checking for template instantiation

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Assuming I have a templated type, e.g.

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct mytype { };
```

How do I write a concept that checks whether a type is an instantiation of that template?

```
template<typename T>
concept MyType = requires(T x) { ??? }
```

I can't figure an obvious way of doing it without resolving to old-style specialised detector types or maybe a marker base type.

Comment: not sure what exactly you are asking. Concepts are not in the standard yet, or did i miss it?

Comment: They are in draft C++20, so of course my question is based on the current draft

Comment: What's the use of this?

Comment: @cpplearner One of such a use case might be perfect forwarding for arguments of a particular type only. Better concepts than SFINAE :)

Comment: @cpplearner The direct and obvious use is enforcing type safety without having to go through the usual verbose template dance. That is, instead of `template<typename A, typename B, typename C> void do_stuff(mytype<A, B, C>)` you could just do `template<MyType T> do_stuff(T)`. And hopefully one day `do_stuff(MyType T)`, as Stroustrup has envisioned.

Comment: @MrMobster: That's not really what concepts are about. You're talking about making a specific usage scenario more convenient. Concepts are about finding a way to express constraints on the capabilities of one or more template arguments. That is, you're not restricting a template to a specific type; you're restricting a template to a specific *interface*, which multiple types could (theoretically) satisfy. Using such a mechanism just so you don't have to type a few extra words is not the point of the thing.

Comment: @NicolBolas I am talking about type safety. And that is what concepts are all about — fixing a huge gap in C++ type system — the fact that templates are not real types but instead macro-like constructs that rely on duck typing. Sure, main advantage of concepts is that they provide type safety around a common API (akin to what protocols and traits do in Swift and Rust), but I also see no reason why they should not be used to provide type safety around a single implementation of a parametrised type as well.

Comment: @MrMobster: It shouldn't provide that because you can already do that, as evidenced by the fact that you wrote the first version. `do_stuff(MyType auto T)` is a far more *obtuse* spelling of what you actually want, since you have to track down the template `MyType` to figure out that it means "an instantiation of `mytype`. I consider that no different from deciding to replace `my_func(int i)` with `my_func(Int auto i)` or some such.

Comment: @NicolBolas so you'd argue that repeating the entire set of template parameters (which are completely irrelevant to the algorithm) every single time results in a better code than a single type specifier? And sure, I agree that  there is a certain logical disconnect between mytype and MyType, which could again be avoided  if templates were proper parametrised types in the system...

Comment: @MrMobster: Better code? Yes. First, it avoids the disconnect I outlined. But equally importantly second, it makes you stop and ask... if `do_stuff` doesn't use those template parameters, why do I *want* my template `do_stuff` function to *only take* a `mytype` instantiation? Why shouldn't I write a proper concept interface, which `do_stuff` can be written against? One that is not *explicitly* dependent on `mytype` itself? It's not like `range::sort` is written against `vector` specifically; it is written against any random access range; `vector` merely provides that interface.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390605/doing-a-static-assert-that-a-template-type-is-another-template

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using C++17 class template argument deduction, you should be able to do something like this:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct mytype { };

template<class T>
concept C1 = requires(T x) { 
    { mytype{x} } -> std::same_as<T>;
};
```

`mytype{x}` uses class template argument deduction to deduce `A`, `B` and `C`, so this is valid if you can construct a `mytype<A, B, C>` from a `T`. In particular, this is valid if `mytype` is copy-constructible since you have an implicitly declared [copy-deduction guide](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#1.3) similar to:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
mytype(mytype<A, B, C>) -> mytype<A, B, C>;
```

Checking that `T` is also the constructed `mytype` instantiation avoid matching other deduction guides, e.g., this would match for any type without the `-> std::same_as<T>`:

```
template <class A, class B, class C>
struct mytype {
    mytype(A);
};

template <class A>
mytype(A) -> mytype<A, A, A>;
```

The proposed solution does not work for non copy-constructible classes, even though should be possible to make it work for move-only classes.

---

Tested with [clang](/questions/tagged/clang) and [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc): https://godbolt.org/z/ojdcrYqKv

Comment: But who's to say A, B and C can be deduced like that?

Comment: @einpoklum There is always an implicitly generated [copy-deduction guide](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#1.3). This guide exists even with a (implicitly) deleted copy-constructor, but in this case the concept will fail (which is specified in my answer).

Comment: You mean, a deduction guide which will manage to deduce A, B and C exactly for those types T which are instantiations of the template?

Comment: I have no idea why anyone would downvote you answer — it is spot on and answers my question exactly.

Comment: @einpoklum Assuming `mytype` has a non-deleted copy-constructor, you have an implicitly generated deduction guide similar to: `template <class A, class B, class C> mystruct(mystruct<A, B, C> const&) -> mystruct<A, B, C>;`, which is the copy-deduction guide.

Comment: This solution does not conform to the C++20 standard. The return type requirement in the requires expression should be a concept, not a type. Replace -> T with -> std::same_as<T>.

Comment: @Holt Could you kindly provide a solution for move-only classes? I am not sure about the correct way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You can define your own meta-function (type trait) for that purpose:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_mytype : std::false_type { };

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct is_mytype<mytype<A, B, C>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T>
concept MyType = is_mytype<T>::value;
```

But to say the truth, I don't know whether there isn't a way how to defining such a concept directly without the need of a separate metafunction.

Comment: Yes, that would have been my solution as well. I was hoping that concepts would make these kind of detectors obsolete.

Comment: @MrMobster It does... once you've written them. Hehe.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a generalized trait to check for specializations:

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> class Z>
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type {};

template <typename... Args, template <typename...> class Z>
struct is_specialization_of<Z<Args...>, Z> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, template <typename...> class Z>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization_of_v = is_specialization_of<T,Z>::value;
```

Which you can make into either a generalized concept:

```
template<typename T, template <typename...> class Z>
concept Specializes = is_specialization_of_v<T, Z>;

template<typename T>
concept MyType = Specializes<T, mytype>;
```

or just a specialized one:

```
template<typename T>
concept MyType = is_specialization_of_v<T, mytype>;
```

Comment: It's not really generalized, as it only works on template classes that themselves take types. So you can't ask if it is a specialization of `std::array` or even `std::span`, since those take non-type template parameters.

Comment: @NicolBolas Vast majority of templates only take type parameters though. So I'd say it's pretty generalized. But yes, it won't work on those two.

Comment: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2098r1.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In the interests of terseness:

```
template<typename T>
concept MyType = requires(T** x) {
    []<typename A, typename B, typename C>(mytype<A, B, C>**){}(x);
};
```

The double-pointer is necessary to avoid derived-to-base conversions, ex. `struct S : mytype<int, int, int> {}`.

This doesn't work in clang at present, since it doesn't allow lambdas in unevaluated context. You can workaround by providing a helper variable template:

```
template<class T> constexpr auto L = []<typename A, typename B, typename C>(mytype<A, B, C>**){};
template<typename T>
concept MyType = requires(T** x) { L<T>(x); };
```

As long as `mytype`'s template arguments are all types, you can make this even terser using placeholders:

```
template<typename T>
concept MyType = requires(T** x) { [](mytype<auto, auto, auto>**){}(x); };
```

At present, this only works in gcc.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I used the last one, but with only single pointers because I _want_ to be able to detect derived classes of the templated type. That's 14 fewer lines of code. \o/

Comment: It seems that `auto` in template arguments of function argument types is not actually standard C++20, although GCC silently allows it :-( Clang does not though, and [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358154/auto-as-a-template-argument-placeholder-for-a-function-parameter) indicates that was only in the Concepts TS but is not valid Standard C++20. So much for GCC's `-std=c++20` flag, then. :-/ I've rewritten without `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

If you give your template class some traits you can do the following:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct mytype {
    using a_type = A;
    using b_type = B;
    using c_type = C;
};
```

With the associate concept:

```
template <typename T>
concept is_mytype =
    std::is_same_v<
        std::remove_const_t<T>,
        mytype<typename T::a_type, typename T::b_type, typename T::c_type>>;
```

Or, if mytype has members of those types you can skip the traits:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct mytype {
    A a_inst;
    B b_inst;
    C c_inst;
};
```

Giving the concept:

```
template <typename T>
concept is_mytype =
    std::is_same_v<
        std::remove_const_t<T>,
        mytype<decltype(T::a_inst), decltype(T::b_inst), decltype(T::c_inst)>>;
```