# C++ concept to check for derived from template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

In [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54191646/5090527) and [this proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2098r1.pdf) we can see an implementation (included below for convenience) for `std::is_specialization_of`, which can detect if a type is a specialization of a given template.

```
template< class T, template<class...> class Primary >
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type {};

template< template<class...> class Primary, class... Args >
struct is_specialization_of< Primary<Args...>, Primary> : std::true_type {};
```

The proposal explicitly says that this type trait is not affected by inheritance:

> The proposed trait considers only specialization. Since specialization is unrelated to inheritance, the trait’s result is unaffected when any template argument happens to be defined via inheritance.

```
template< class > struct B { };
template< class T > struct D : B<T> { };

static_assert(     is_specialization_of_v< B<int>, B> );
static_assert(     is_specialization_of_v< D<int>, D> );

static_assert( not is_specialization_of_v< B<int>, D> );
static_assert( not is_specialization_of_v< D<int>, B> );
```

Is there a way to implement something that *does* take inheritance into consideration, behaving like [`std::derived_from`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/derived_from) but where the `Base` could be any specialization of a given template? Something like, say `std::derived_from_specialization_of`:

```
template<class>   struct A {};
template<class T> struct B : A<T> {};
template<class T> struct C : B<T> {};

static_assert(derived_from_specialization_of< A<int>, A>);
static_assert(derived_from_specialization_of< B<int>, B>);
static_assert(derived_from_specialization_of< C<int>, C>);

static_assert(derived_from_specialization_of< B<int>, A>);
static_assert(derived_from_specialization_of< C<int>, B>);
static_assert(derived_from_specialization_of< C<int>, A>);
```

It should also support templates with multiple parameters, and/or parameter packs:

```
template<class, class> struct A{};
template<typename...>  struct B{};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[De-`_Ugly`-fied rom MSVCSTL](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/3c2fd04d441d46ec9d914d9cbb621a3bac96c3a5/stl/inc/xutility#L2684-L2690):

```
template <template <class...> class Template, class... Args>
void derived_from_specialization_impl(const Template<Args...>&);

template <class T, template <class...> class Template>
concept derived_from_specialization_of = requires(const T& t) {
    derived_from_specialization_impl<Template>(t);
};
```

which [we use to implement the exposition-only type trait *`is-derived-from-view-interface`*](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/3c2fd04d441d46ec9d914d9cbb621a3bac96c3a5/stl/inc/xutility#L2696-L2698) from [[range.view]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.view#6).

Note that this has the same limitation as the `is_specialization_of` trait cited in the OP: it works only with templates that have all type parameters.

[**[DEMO]**](https://godbolt.org/z/6Pjvxesd1)