# Template operator on difference but related types

Tags: c++, templates

I am implementing some matrix operations for my templated `matrix<T>` and `matrix_view<T>`.
At first I had

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
matrix<common_type_t<T, U>> operator+(matrix_view<T>, matrix_view<U>);
```

and expected it to work also for `matrix`

```cpp
matrix<int> a, b;
auto c = a + b;
```

because there is a converting constructor from `matrix<T>` to `matrix_view<T>`.

But it didn't work, because of the "Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions" rule.

So I added another overload

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
matrix<common_type_t<T, U>> operator+(matrix<T>, matrix<U>);
```

But the story is still not over, for `operator+` between `matrix<T>` and `matrix_view<T>`, I need to define another two overloads to make them work.

Now I wonder if I have to define all four overloads for every matrix operation. That's a lot of boilerplate code. And indeed the number of overloads needed grows exponentially with the number of types involved, if I am to add some other types in the future.

Is there any solution to this problem? Preferably only requiring me to define the first overload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a concept:

```
template<typename C>
concept matrix_c = requires(C const& c) { [] <typename ... X>(matrix<X ...> const&) {}(c); }
                || requires(C const& c) { [] <typename ... X>(matrix_view<X ...> const&) {}(c); }

auto operator+(matrix_c auto&& m1, matrix_c auto&& m2);
```

This solution will work for all combinations of `matrix_view` and `matrix`.

Note that the concept can be simplified if you use, e.g., a common base class `matrix_base`, as it's usual in expression template code. It'll work, however, also for completely unrelated classes.

Comment: Thanks! The concept solution is really interesting, though I think the common base solution is more appropriate here.

Comment: @Masquue: if you have a common base class, you could simply pass the parameters by const ref to this class, e.g. `operator+(matrix_base<T> const&, matrix_base<U> const&)`. This is what standard libraries such as Eigen do.

Comment: Wouldn't it be equivalent to check `std::is_convertible`?

Comment: @AndyG: you mean `std::convertible` instead of the immeduately invoked lamda expressions (IILE)? Yes, that could work here as well, and probably easier. I just like the IILE, because you can directly include the template arguments. That is, one gets a `std::convertible` on the template template level.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I decided to be my solution, by traditionally specializing a helper template class.

@davidhigh 's immediately invoked lambda expressions (IILE) solution or the `std::convertible` semantics might not mean as accurately as what I want here.

```cpp
// `is_specialization_of` shamelessly copied from this question
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70130735/c-concept-to-check-for-derived-from-template-specialization
template <typename T, template<typename...> typename Primary>
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type {};

template <template<typename...> typename Primary, typename... Args>
struct is_specialization_of<Primary<Args...>, Primary> : std::true_type {};

// somehow I need to relax the condition a little to also allow const T and T&
template <template<typename...> typename Primary, typename T>
struct is_specialization_of<T&, Primary> : is_specialization_of<T, Primary> {};

template <template<typename...> typename Primary, typename T>
struct is_specialization_of<const T, Primary> : is_specialization_of<T, Primary> {};

template <typename T, template<typename...> typename Primary>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization_of_v = is_specialization_of<T, Primary>::value;

template <typename T>
concept matrix_like = is_specialization_of_v<T, matrix> ||
                      is_specialization_of_v<T, matrix_view>;
```

Comment: This solution may be overly restrictive. It only allows matrix and matrix_view. You may wish to allow any type that is convertible to a matrix_view

Comment: @AndyG Indeed, I intentionally wish to disallow any type that may be implicitly converted to `matrix` or `matrix_view` (and currently I don't have such conversions other than between these two). If something is really "like a matrix" and I want to allow it, then I can add it directly into `matrix_like`.