# Detect if a type is a std::tuple?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples, type-traits

Currently I have two functions :

```
template<typename Type> bool f(Type* x);
template<typename... List> bool f(std::tuple<List...>* x);
```

Is there any way to merge these two functions with an extra template parameter that indicates whether the passed type is a tuple ?

```
template<typename Type, bool IsTuple = /* SOMETHING */> bool f(Type* x);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure, using [`is_specialization_of`](https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/wheels/src/default/include/wheels/meta/type_traits.h%2B%2B#cl-161) (link taken and fixed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251376/how-can-i-check-if-a-type-is-an-instantiation-of-a-given-class-template#comment14786989_11251408)):

```
template<typename Type, bool IsTuple = is_specialization_of<Type, std::tuple>::value>
bool f(Type* x);
```

The question is, however, do you really want that? Normally, if you need to know if a type is a tuple, you need special handling for tuples, and that usually has to do with its template arguments. As such, you might want to stick to your overloaded version.

**Edit:** Since you mentioned you only need a small portion specialized, I recommend overloading but only for the small special part:

```
template<class T>
bool f(T* x){
  // common parts...
  f_special_part(x);
  // common parts...
}
```

with

```
template<class T>
void f_special_part(T* x){ /* general case */ }

template<class... Args>
void f_special_part(std::tuple<Args...>* x){ /* special tuple case */ }
```

Comment: In normal time this could be dangerous and a specialization would be preferable. But this function is a large function, and only a small `if` inside change whether tuple type or not.

Comment: Using an extra template parameter also means it's possible to explicitly call `f<tuple<...>, false>`, or `f<int, true>`, which could be avoided by checking `is_specialization_of` in the function body.

Comment: @Vincent: Then I'd actually recommend tag-dispatching instead of a runtime `if`. :)

Comment: `static if`, we need yooooooou

Comment: in C++ 17, you can use `constexpr if`

Answer (score 18):

With C++17, here is a fairly simple solution using [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If)

```
template <typename> struct is_tuple: std::false_type {};

template <typename ...T> struct is_tuple<std::tuple<T...>>: std::true_type {};
```

Then you can do something like:

```
template<typename Type> bool f(Type* x) {
    if constexpr (is_tuple<Type>::value) {
        std::cout << "A tuple!!\n";
        return true;
    }

    std::cout << "Not a tuple\n";
    return false;
}
```

A test to ensure it worked:

```
f(&some_tuple);
f(&some_object);
```

Output:

> A tuple!!
>   Not a tuple

---

*Solution taken in part from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16337657/2089675) found here: [How to know if a type is a specialization of std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337610/how-to-know-if-a-type-is-a-specialization-of-stdvector)*

Comment: Your first snippet uses SFINAE, which is enough in itself. `if constexpr` adds nothing to the solution

Answer (score 6):

With C++11, this is my preferred pattern:

```
// IsTuple<T>()
template <typename T>
struct IsTupleImpl : std::false_type {};

template <typename... U>
struct IsTupleImpl<std::tuple <U...>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool IsTuple() {
  return IsTupleImpl<decay_t<T>>::value;
}
```

Works great. No dependencies (I can't use Boost).

Answer (score 5):

You could just have your functions defer to another function:

```
template<typename Type,bool IsTuple> bool f(Type *x);

template<typename Type> 
inline bool f(Type* x) { return f<Type,false>(x); }

template<typename... List> 
inline bool f(std::tuple<List...>* x) { return f<std::tuple<List...>,true>(x); }
```

Answer (score 4):

Might be a little late but you can also do something like this, in a more modern c++17 style with template variables:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool IsTuple = false;
template<typename ... types>
constexpr bool IsTuple<std::tuple<types...>>   = true;
```

And some tests

```
struct TestStruct{};

static_assert(IsTuple<int> == false,                "Doesn't work with literal.");
static_assert(IsTuple<TestStruct> == false,         "Doesn't work with classes.");
static_assert(IsTuple<std::tuple<int, char>>,       "Doesn't work with plain tuple.");
static_assert(IsTuple<std::tuple<int&, char&>>,     "Doesn't work with lvalue references");
static_assert(IsTuple<std::tuple<int&&, char&&>>,   "Doesn't work with rvalue references");
```

You can view it here https://godbolt.org/z/FYI1jS

EDIT:
You will want to run std::decay, std::remove_volatile, std::remove_const to handle special cases.

Comment: Most laconic solution and therefore best one.