# Implementation of std::list<bool>

Tags: c++

Does `std::list<bool>` have, by similar madness, an explicit specialisation like `std::vector<bool>`?

Is `std::vector<bool>` the only C++ Standard Library container to be thus afflicted?

Is there some kind of `traits` I can use to detect the specialisation?

Comment: No, `std::list` has no specializations.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do feel free to put that as an answer though.

Comment: Also, as for detection, similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337610/how-to-know-if-a-type-is-a-specialization-of-stdvector

Comment: I would hardly imagine usefulness of `std::list<bool>`

Comment: I agree. It's difficult to see how you could build a linked list without being able to take an explicit address of the datum in a node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As seen in the standard, [`std::vector<bool>`](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.bool) has it's own paragraph which dictates it's implementation. The requirement for `std::list` having one is not there, that doesn't mean an implementation is not allowed to *not* have one however. And as far as I know, `std::vector` is the only container that is required to have a specialization for `bool`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll upvote this. But I guess if an implementation did have one then it would have to obey exactly the same rules as one which didn't have a specialisation?

Comment: @XavierImbs Correct.

Comment: @XavierImbs That's right, but the standard requirements mean an explicit specialisation of `std::list<bool>` would probably be useless. The standard requirements implicitly disallow packing multiple bits into a single byte. That's the reason why the requirements for `std::vector<bool>` are different from those for other `std::vector<T>`s: it's specifically to allow such packing.