# is_specialization type trait for a static constexpr member

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-specialization, type-traits

I need a type trait that determines if a class is a specialization of a given template. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337610/how-to-know-if-a-type-is-a-specialization-of-stdvector) provides an implementation that works in most cases.

However, it does not seem to work for static constexpr member types. In the following example (also available on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IcV2QbaY6iug3Ipp)), the last static_assert fails on Clang and GCC trunk:

```
#include <type_traits>

// from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337610/how-to-know-if-a-type-is-a-specialization-of-stdvector
template<typename Test, template<typename...> class Ref>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> class Ref, typename... Args>
struct is_specialization<Ref<Args...>, Ref>: std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct bar {
  bool x;
};

struct foo {
  bar<int> y;
  static constexpr bar<bool> z{true};
};

int main() {
  static_assert(is_specialization<decltype(foo::y), bar>{});
  static_assert(is_specialization<decltype(foo::z), bar>{});
}
```

I have two questions: is this correct behavior, and how can I write a type trait that will work when I refer to the type of a static constexpr member?

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that works if you decay the type of the static constexpr member to strip the cv-qualifiers.

```
static_assert(is_specialization<std::decay_t<decltype(foo::z)>, bar>{});
```