# Check if two types are of the same template

Tags: c++, sfinae, type-traits

I want to check if two types are of the same template. As an example I want the following snippet of code to return `true` because both objects are vectors despite the inner elements being of different types.

It's important that the check is made at compile time (that's why the function is constexpr).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <typename Container1, typename Container2> constexpr bool CheckTypes(Container1 c1, Container2 c2)
{
    return std::is_same<Container1,Container2>::value;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v1(100,0);
  std::vector<double> v2(100,0);
  std::cout << CheckTypes(v1,v2);
}
```

Comment: If you need to check something at compile time, you should operate with rather static types than with variables.

Comment: But they are not of the same type... The container is the same, not the instantiated type. You can check using `sizeof`, but I'm not sure how elegant of a solution that would be.

Comment: I want it to work with any container.

Comment: Why do you want to check this?

Comment: @Sombrero not quite happy with the dup. This Q is a bit different. OP gives `std::vector`as an example, but their questions is more general than that: _"I want to check if two types are of the same template"_.

Comment: @YSC I know the dup only asks the case for vector but the answer on that question answers it for every other specialization. That's why I hammered it. The question title is sub-optimal I agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
template <class T, class U>
struct are_same_template : std::is_same<T, U>
{};

template <template<class...> class T, class T1, class T2>
struct are_same_template<T<T1>, T<T2>> : std::true_type
{};

template <class T, class U>
constexpr bool CheckTypes(T, U)
{
    return are_same_template<T, U>::value;
}
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8533c694968f4dbb

---

This works by providing a specialization of `are_same_template` that discard the template argument types:

```
template <template<class...> class T, class T1, class T2>
struct are_same_template<T<T1>, T<T2>>
```

Even if `T1` and `T2` differ (the template argument types), `are_same_template` is a true type:

```
are_same_template<T<T1>, T<T2>> : std::true_type
```

---

About `template<class...>` instead of `template<class>`: this is to accomodate the fact than `std::` containers have implicit template arguments. Thanks to ConstantinosGlynos for making me aware of it.

Comment: I like this approach, but why isn't it working here: https://rextester.com/LRJ63332

Comment: I tried with g++, vc++ and clang.. All return the same result. The only difference is the c++17 flag. Godbolt also returns 0. https://godbolt.org/z/tVKxiv

Comment: I have a feeling that there's something horribly wrong with `Coliru`. Tried it with several compilers and platforms (`rextester, ideone, Qt` and `godbolt`). All give the same result (`false`) even with the `c++17` flag on. I think the `Coliru` compiler is acting up...

Comment: I don't think so... Because then it means `g++` and `vc++` have the same bug. Coliru is also using `g++`. Also, I was thinking, the `std::vector` container has a second template parameter for the `std::allocator`. The partial specialization does not include that parameter which makes me think that it's not the one being selected. Sweeet (i was right): https://rextester.com/MRXAQ82842

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos You're terribly right, and I'm wrong. This is an easy fix then :) Thank you.

Comment: And what happens if the class has two template parameters, one typename and one of a known type. For example `template <class T, bool Resize = true> class vector;`

Comment: @user28032019 try it for yourself ;) This answer manages simple types, simple templates, and now `std::` template containers. If you want something more exotic, please say so in the question.

Comment: @user28032019: Then you can specialize for that type. `std::array` takes two parameters for example (type and size). I still think this is a good idea. Partial class template specialization can be employed for all std containers.

Comment: Why the downvote now that the code has been fixed though?

Comment: @YSC: The fixed code works in all compilers and platforms! :-)

Comment: @YSC Your answer is fine and it's the accepted one. Can you help me now with a slighty different one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396786/check-if-class-is-a-template-specialization

Answer (score 2):

In case you would like to check if two template template classes are the same without specializing them:

```
template<template<typename...> class ATT, template<typename...> class BTT>
struct is_same_tt : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> class TT>
struct is_same_tt<TT, TT> : std::true_type {};

// example
static_assert(is_same_tt<std::tuple, std::tuple>());
static_assert(!is_same_tt<std::vector, std::list>());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can but it take a little of metaprog :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

template <typename Container1, typename Container2> 
struct CheckTypes_impl
{
    constexpr static bool check (Container1 , Container2 ) { return false; }
};

template <
    template <class...> class Container1, class...  args1 ,  class...  args2 > 
struct CheckTypes_impl<Container1<args1...>,Container1<args2...>>
{
    constexpr static bool check (Container1<args1...> , Container1<args2...> ) { return true; }
};


template < 
        template <class...> class Container1,
        class ... args1,
        template <class...> class Container2,
        class ... args2
    > constexpr bool CheckTypes(Container1<args1...> c1, Container2<args2...> c2)
{
    return CheckTypes_impl<Container1<args1...>,Container2<args2...>>::check(c1,c2);
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v1(100,0);
  std::vector<double> v2(100,0);
  std::set<int> s;
  std::cout << CheckTypes(v1,v2)  << std::endl;
  std::cout << CheckTypes(v1,s)  << std::endl;
}
```

run : 
https://wandbox.org/permlink/OTuQfl7UBlbxgtCO

Update : You need " template  class Container1, class..." because vector don't take 1 template param, but 2. In the general case you don't know how many default parameters will be used

Answer (score 0):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337610/how-to-know-if-a-type-is-a-specialization-of-stdvector). They provide a way to check if something is a specialization of a template class:

```
template<typename Test, template<typename...> class Ref>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> class Ref, typename... Args>
struct is_specialization<Ref<Args...>, Ref>: std::true_type {};
```

And probably do something like this to keep your original interface:

```
template <typename Container1, typename Container2> 
constexpr bool CheckTypes(Container1 c1, Container2 c2) {
    return is_specialization<Container1, std::vector>::value && is_specialization<Container2, std::vector>::value;
}
```

So you can do something like this:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1(100,0);
    std::vector<double> v2(100,0);
    std::cout << CheckTypes(v1,v2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what happens if the class has two template parameters, one typename and one of a known type. For example `template <class T, bool Resize = true> class vector;`