# Get types of tuple as template parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a function-template called `serialize` which takes a template parameter like this:

```
template <typename T>
std::string serialize(T const & t);
```

I have different use-cases for `serialize` and they depend on `T`.

- In general, `serialize` shall just throw an exception.
- If `T` is a `std::vector`, serialize each item using `serialize<Item>` with `T=std::vector<Item>`.
- If `T` is a `std::map`, serialize each key and value separately using `serialize<K>` and `serialize<V>` with `T=std::map<K,V>`.
- If `T` is a `std::tuple`, serialize each component using `serialize<Ci>` with i in {0, n-1} where n is the size of the tuple and `Ci` is the type of the component at position i.

I figured I could use `std::enable_if` with `is_specialization` to differentiate those cases, which is why I wrote them like this:

```
template <typename T>
std::string serialize(T const & t) { throw std::exception(); }

template <typename TVec,
          typename T = std::enable_if<is_specialization<TVec, std::vector>, TVec::value_type>::type>
std::string serialize(TVec const & tvec) { /*Something with serialize<Item>*/ }

template <typename KVMap,
          typename K = std::enable_if<is_specialization<TMap, std::map>, KVMap::key_type>::type,
          typename V = std::enable_if<is_specialization<TMap, std::map>, KVMap::mapped_type>::type>
std::string serialize(KVMap const & kvmap) { /*Something with serialize<K> and serialize<V>*/ }
```

And of course, here's the implementation of `is_specialization` : [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337610/how-to-know-if-a-type-is-a-specialization-of-stdvector)

You'll notice I didn't provide an implementation for the `std::tuple`-case, which is because I don't know how to write that one. My first impulse was to do something along the lines of:

```
template <typename Tuple,
          ???>
std::string serialize(Tuple const & tup) { /*Something with serialize<Ci> for different Ci*/ }
```

But how do I get `Ci`? Do you have an idea how to correctly write the `std::tuple`-case?

I tried to replace `???` with an `std::enable_if` to find out whether `Tuple` is a `std::tuple`, but unlike the cases with `std::vector` and `std::map` I cannot get a parameter-pack containing the tuples' types from the tuple-class itself... or can I? I really don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
std::string serialize(const std::tuple<Ts...>&) { /* ... */ }
```

?

Comment: You were right. I'm implementing the `template <typename T> T deserialize(std::string const & tstr)` in parallel and because the compiler cannot resolve `T` in that case, I started using `std::enable_if` and `is_specialization` when I didn't need it for `template <typename T> std::string serialize(T const & t)`. It was my oversight.

Answer (score 0):

> I figured I could use `std::enable_if` with `is_specialization` to differentiate those cases.

Simpler would be to use regular template method:

```
template <typename T>
std::string serialize(T const&) { throw std::exception(); }

template <typename T>
std::string serialize(const std::vector<T>& v) {
    std::string res;

    for (const auto& e : v) {
        res += serialize(e);
    }
    return res;
}

template <typename K, typename V>
std::string serialize(const std::map<K, V>& m) {
    std::string res;

    for (const auto& p : m) {
        res += serialize(p.first);
        res += serialize(p.second);
    }
    return res;
}

#if 1 // std::apply for pre-c++17

template <typename F, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
auto apply_impl(F&& f, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
-> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...))
{
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...);
}

template <typename F, typename Tuple>
auto apply(F&& f, Tuple&& tuple)
-> decltype(apply_impl(f, tuple, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>()))
{
    return apply_impl(f, tuple, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>());
}

#endif


template <typename... Ts>
std::string serialize(const std::tuple<Ts...>& t) {
    return apply([](const auto&... args){
        std::string res;
#if 0 // For C++17
        (res += serialize(args), ...);
#else
        const int dummy[] = {0, (res += serialize(args), void(), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable
#endif
        return res;
    }, t);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/81nj7jY3f)

Comment: That looks mighty impressive, but I don't know how to read half of the code. Also, when I copied this code into an online ide, it didn't work (and because I don't particularly understand it I couldn't fix it myself.)

Comment: Typo fixed and demo added.