# Obtain all-but-last parameter of variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a ctor declared like this:

```
template<typename... Coords>
MyClass<T>(vector<T> values, Coords... coords) { /* code */ }
```

I want it to look like this:

```
template<typename... Coords>
MyClass<T>(Coords... coords, vector<T> values) { /* code */ }
```

but the standard requires the variadic argument to be the last. If I write something like

```
template<typename... Args>
MyClass<T>(Args... coordsThenValues) { /* code */ }
```

how would I split `coordsThenValues` into an all-but-last parameter pack `Coords... coords` and the last parameter `vector<T> values`?

Comment: Do you like tuples?  How do you like [dem tuples](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you like tuples?

How do you like forward as tuple?

```
struct foo {
  template<class...Ts>
  foo(Ts&&...ts):
    foo(
      magic<0>{}, // sent it to the right ctor
      std::index_sequence< sizeof...(ts)-1 >{}, // the last shall be first
      std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(ts)-1>{}, // the first shall be last
      std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) // bundled args
    )
  {}
private:
  template<size_t>
  struct magic {};
  template<size_t...I0s, size_t...I1s, class...Ts>
  foo(
    magic<0>, // tag
    std::index_sequence<I0s...>, // first args
    std::index_sequence<I1s...>, // last args
    std::tuple<Ts...> args // all args
  ):
    foo(
      magic<1>{}, // dispatch to another tagged ctor
      std::get<I0s>(std::move(args))..., // get first args
      std::get<I1s>(std::move(args))... // and last args
    )
  {}
  // this ctor gets the args in an easier to understand order:
  template<class...Coords>
  foo(magic<1>, std::vector<T> values, Coords...coords) {
  }
};
```

here the public ctor packs up the arguments into a tuple of references (possibly l, possibly r).  It also gets two sets of indexes.

It then sends it to `magic<0>` ctor, which shuffles the arguments around so that the last one is first (assuming the indexes are right).

The `magic<1>` ctor gets the vector first, then the coords.

Basically I shuffled the arguments around so the last one became first.

`magic` just exists to make me not have to think much about overload resolution, and make which ctor I'm forwarding to explicit.  It would probably work without it, but I like tagging when I'm doing something crazy with ctor forwarding.

Comment: Should be `std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)`, other than that this is perfect.

Comment: I modified your code somewhat. The main problem is: `foo(Ts&&...ts)` catches *everything*. If the `magic<0>` ctor tries to pass to the `magic<1>` ctor with invalid args, the passing will fail and it will actually call `foo(Ts&&...ts)` causing an infinite compiler loop. So instead of `template<class...Ts>`, I wrote `template<class...Ts, typename = std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Ts) > 1 && !(is_magic<NthTypeOf<0, Ts...>>::value))>::type>`. (I moved `magic` outside the class definition and wrote a simple `is_magic` and `NthTypeOf`).

Comment: @arcinde One of the points of `magic` is that nobody else (besides the class) has the right to create it.  Which that subverts.

Comment: It's not so bad if the constructors that take it are private? `magic` is not exposed in any way. The only reason I did it is because I was running into annoying issues with templated structs inside a templated class.

Comment: `template<size_t n> static std::true_type is_magic_f( magic<n> ) { return {}; } template<class T> static std::false_type is_magic_f( T ) { return {}; } template<class T> using is_magic = decltype( is_magic_f( std::declval<T>() ) );` ;)

Comment: Hmm, in the `magic<1>{}` constructor call of foo, I spot `args` being `std::move`d twice; won't one of these invalidate `args` for the other parameter being evaluated? Or is the real moving only really being done on the `std::get`ed value?

Comment: @rubenvb `std::move` does not move, `std::forward` does not forward.  Both are just casts-to-rvalue, any moving happens within the consuming function.  The behaviour of `std::get` is like a member access; when it moves, it only moves that one element being gotten.  If the indexes overlapped, then there would be a problem.

Comment: @Yakk, right, so those are really only "move"ing the parameters extracted by get. (note the quotes, I know std::move doesn't move, but I do know the stuff around the move can actually move stuff that is std::move'd). And now I've given myself a headache. Perhaps std::move'ing some aspirin somewhere might help with that.

Comment: I think there is still one issue in this implementation. `std::tuple<Ts&&...> ` won't work as you (probably) expect.`Ts&&` won't be forwarding references, they will be regular rvalue references. You can see this is a problem if you try to use `const char*` instead of Coords: https://godbolt.org/z/8K16xKehT

The solution is to use a template parameter for tuple instead of `std::tuple<Ts&&...>`, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450892/perfect-forwarding-and-stdtuple

After this change, it works fine with `const char*`: https://godbolt.org/z/fPGq8PM6c

Comment: @igor or just remove the `&&` there