# Perfect forwarding of arguments through a tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

I have a function which ideally should look like this:

```
template<typename... t_buffers, t_function function>
void iterate_buffers(t_buffers &&... buffers, t_function &&function);
```

However, the parameter pack types can't be deduced unless it comes last, so instead my function signature is the following:

```
template<typename... t_buffers_and_function>
void iterate_bufferes(t_buffers_and_function &&... buffers_and_function);
```

The arguments then get shuffled around so that the function comes first. To perform this shuffling, I'm using the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255890/obtain-all-but-last-parameter-of-variadic-template), but I'm hitting an issue when attempting to forward the tuple.

Here is a simplified example which has the problem:

```
template<typename... t_args>
void inner(std::tuple<t_args &&...> args) {};

template<typename... t_args>
void outer(t_args &&... args) {
    inner(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<t_args>(args)...));
}
```

If I pass rvalues (e.g. by calling `outer(1, 2);`), it works as expected. However if instead I pass lvalues (`int x = 1; int y = 2; outer(x, y);`), I get the following syntax error:

```
error: could not convert ‘std::forward_as_tuple(_Elements&& ...) [with _Elements = {int&, int&}]((* & std::forward<int&>((* & args#1))))’ from ‘std::tuple<int&, int&>’ to ‘std::tuple<int&&, int&&>’
inner(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<t_args>(args)...));
~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So `forward_as_tuple` has produced a tuple of lvalue references `std::tuple<int&, int&>` as expected, since the values provided to `outer` are lvalues. Shouldn't `inner` accept a tuple of either rvalues or lvalues, since `std::tuple<t_args &&...> args` is using forwarding references? Why is it complaining about not being able to convert to rvalues? Are forwarding references disallowed in that context (since args is not simply `T &&`) so `args` is forced to be a tuple of rvalues only? (The examples I've found online seem to use `std::tuple<t_args &&...>` syntax.)

The error goes away if I remove the usage of forwarding references from `inner`: `void inner(std::tuple<t_args...> args)`. Then the type of `args` is `std::tuple<int&, int&>` if I pass lvalues to `outer`, and `std::tuple<int&&, int&&>` if I pass rvalues. Maybe forwarding references aren't needed here because the correct lvalue/rvalue types have already been encoded into the tuple and don't need forwarding? I'm confused because all the examples I see online (including the one I linked) use the original call signature for `inner` which has forwarding references.

Comment: A smaller example is "Why can't `template<typename T> void test(std::tuple<T&&>);` be called as `test(std::tuple<int&>{i});` (with `T = int&`)". A minimal example here: https://godbolt.org/z/nh19of

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that `std::tuple<T&&>` isn't a tuple of a forwarding reference, but rather is a tuple of rvalue references? [Scott Meyers gives two examples:](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) `f(std::vector<T>&&)` is an rvalue reference and `f(T &&)` is a forwarding reference. Perhaps my misunderstanding is that I thought anytime `T&&` appears in a parameter, that portion of the type gets interpreted as a forwarding reference (the vector example still fails under that rule), but actually, only `T&&` _exactly_ as the whole parameter works?