# Simplify template has_field with C++17/20

Tags: c++, templates

Given next working solution:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_value_t : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct has_value_t<T, decltype(T::value, void())> : std::true_type { };

template<typename T>
constexpr bool has_value = has_value_t<T>::value;
```

<sub>Idea was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14523787/3743145</sub>

I wonder if there a C++17/20 more laconic way to achieve same effect. Like

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool has_value = .....;
```

Usage:

```
template<typename T>
enable_if_t<has_value<T>,
std::ostream&> operator<<(std::ostream& os, T const& arg)
{
    return os << arg.value;
}
```

Comment: There is potentially [std::experimental::is_detected](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If C++20 is on the table, you can do that with a concept that checks a simple requirement

```
template <typename T>
concept has_value = requires(T) {
    T::value;
};

template<typename T> requires has_value<T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, T const& arg)
{
    return os << arg.value;
}
```

`T::value` being a well formed expression is being checked in the requires expression. Pretty straight forward to write, and to use as a constraint on a template.

Comment: Is there a way in concepts to assert `T::value` is public filed?

Comment: @kyb - This already does it. The scope of the requires expression is not inside the class. If `value` is inaccessible publicly, the expression won't be well-formed.

Answer (score 3):

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)

```
template<typename,typename=void> constexpr bool has_value = false;
template<typename T>             constexpr bool has_value<T,decltype(T::value,void())> = true;
```

[Test](https://godbolt.org/z/pYegdG)

```
struct V { int value; };
struct W { int walue; };

static_assert(has_value<V>);
static_assert(not has_value<W>);
```

<sub>Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52291518/3743145</sub>