# Check if type is specialization of template for both type and non-type template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I've been trying to implement checking to see if a type is a specialization of a specific template. I have seen quite a few answers online, but most of them only work for type parameters.

I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15175896/14815117) that does cover non-type parameters. However, it is undesirable since it wraps them in a struct which is making it very difficult to create a concept for it. It also requires explicitly specifying the non-type template parameters.

I have come up with the following that comes from the answers I've seen online. But for the non-type version, I would have to create a new version for each parameter type (I've used bool... below as an example).

```
template <template <typename...> typename C, typename   T> struct type_instance_impl : public std::false_type {};
template <template <typename...> typename C, typename...T> struct type_instance_impl<C, C<T...>> : public std::true_type {};
template <template <typename...> typename C, typename   T> concept instance_of_type = type_instance_impl<C, std::decay_t<T>>::value;

template <template <bool    ...> typename C, typename   T> struct non_type_instance_impl : public std::false_type {};
template <template <bool    ...> typename C, bool    ...T> struct non_type_instance_impl<C, C<T...>> : public std::true_type {};
template <template <bool    ...> typename C, typename   T> concept instance_of_non_type = non_type_instance_impl<C, std::decay_t<T>>::value;
```

Usage:

```
template <bool...> class bools;

int main(){
  std::cout << instance_of_type<std::complex, std::complex<double>>;
  std::cout << instance_of_non_type<bools, bools<true, false, true>>;

  return 0;
}
```

Is there a solution that will allow for any non-type parameter (and any amount of parameters)?

I would also like if both the type and non-type version could be combined into a single concept but that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to mention every type, you can use `auto` instead since C++17 to cover all types of non-type parameters. (An exception are reference types which require `auto&`, and so you can't cover them in one declaration. But they are rarely used. Maybe `decltype(auto)` is supposed to work for both, but I am not entirely sure.)

However, for your last request you would need to implement every possible combination of type or non-type parameters. There is currently no way in the standard to define a template or template template parameter that allows both a type and a non-type template argument for a given template parameter. (And if you want to also include template template parameters in the set of choices, then you would need to apply all combinations recursively as well.)

[P1985](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/735) proposes to unify different kinds of template parameters so that this becomes possible.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize `auto` could be used as a non-type template parameter. I have been hurting my head learning about template templates today, I really appreciate this answer.

Comment: You can use `decltype(auto)` for reference and non-reference non-type parameters: <https://godbolt.org/z/EnT95oros>. The proposal you were thinking of was probably [P1985 "Universal Template Parameters"](https://wg21.link/P1985R3) which proposed `template auto` for type-, non-type- and template- template parameters.

Comment: @Artyer I don't think it is obvious that `decltype(auto)` should work. At least I think you also need it in the template template parameter. I wasn't aware that there was an update of the paper this year (and also I though the first revision was older).