# C++ - Know if a type / class is nested?

Tags: c++, templates, nested, traits

After seeing many examples of metaprogramming in C++ that allow for figuring out may properties of classes (such as [knowing if a type is a specialization of a template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251408/399580) ), or knowing if a class incorporates a given nested type; but I was wondering if is was possible to write a test or trait that determines the inverse of the last one - to check if a given `Type` is nested within a `class` or `struct`.

In other words, I'm looking for the equivalent of the following pseudocode:

```
template <typename Type> struct is_nested {
    enum { value = {__some magic__} };
};

typedef int type1;
struct Something { typedef int internal_type; };
typedef Something::internal_type type2;

//...later, likely at a different scope

is_nested< int >::value; // yields false
is_nested< std::vector<int>::iterator >::value; // yields true
is_nested< type1 >::value; // yields false
is_nested< type2 >::value; // yields true
```

I know I can use `sizeof` to implement yes/no tests, and I presume `Type` is part of those tests, but I can't figure out how to plug in some sort of "any viable type" into the test such that I can form an expression like `Anytype::Type`.

```
template 
struct is_nested
{
    typedef char yes;
    typedef struct { char u[2]; } no;

    // Herein lies the problem
    ???? static yes test( char [ sizeof(Anytype::Type) ] ) ;
    ???? static no test(...);


public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};
```

(Note that I don't care nor (can afford to) know *what* type would `Type` be nested in; all it matters is if it is nested in *something* or not. In other words, this trait should *only* depend on `Type`.)

I'm looking for a C++ solution be it in C++11 or C++03, but in the first case I would welcome it much more if it was backportable.

Comment: What is the problem that this is intended to solve?

Comment: I'm mostly theorizing on how to improve my [adaption of typesafe enums in C++03](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11856721/399580) by disabling relational operators for `enum`s which are nested inside structs; this is one of two approaches I'm studying to tackle that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible, but not due to a technical limitation, rather because you can't always tell whether a type name identifies a nested type or not - and templates work with *types*, not names.

In this case, for instance:

```
is_nested< std::vector<int>::iterator >::value
```

You do not know what `iterator` is. Consider this class `my_vector`:

```
template<typename T>
struct my_vector
{
    typedef T* iterator;
    // ...
};
```

What should `is_nested<my_vector<int>::iterator>::value` yield? You probably expect the result to be `true`.

However, what is nested here is the *alias*, not the type itself: the type `int*` is not nested. In fact, I expect you would wish the following to yield `false`:

```
is_nested<int*>::value
```

So here the same `is_nested<T>` trait should yield two different results given the same type `T` (`int*`, in this case). The information based on which `is_nested<>` should define `value` cannot be retrieved from the type `T` itself - and templates work with types, not names.

Comment: Excellent point on the matter of pointer-as-iterator and other similar situations that could arise. At that point though I'd expect the compiler to be able to solve it as the iterator _type_ is known; in such case, this trait would for example help determine if a container type has contiguous storage (would definitively yield `false` if the iterator type is a raw pointer, and _likely_ yield `true` otherwise).

Comment: @LuisMachuca: Not sure what you mean when you say "to solve *it*". What do you mean by "it"? Your `is_nested<>` trait would get a *type* in input, which in both cases is `int*`. That's everything `is_nested<>` knows. There is no way you can program `is_nested<>` to produce different results given the same template arguments.

Comment: …True, unfortunately. This means I'll have to discard this approach.

Comment: @LuisMachuca: I'm afraid so :(

Comment: Um, at this point I should ask what is the correct protocol here? Is the question marked as answered-but-not-solved, closed overall, or...?

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to check if the "canonical type" (the result type after all aliases are resolved) is nested using non-standard features of compilers.

[CTTI](https://github.com/Manu343726/ctti) can get the name of a type at compile time. Then find `:` in the string:

```
#include <vector>
#include "ctti/type_id.hpp"

constexpr bool has_colon(const ctti::detail::string& s, size_t i) {
    return i < s.length() ? (s[i] == ':' || has_colon(s, i + 1)) : false;
}

template<typename T>
using is_nested = integral_constant<bool, has_colon(ctti::type_id<T>().name(), 0)>;

typedef int type1;
struct Something { typedef int internal_type; };
typedef Something::internal_type type2;

static_assert(!is_nested< int >::value, "");
static_assert(is_nested< std::vector<int>::iterator >::value, "");
static_assert(!is_nested< type1 >::value, "");
// static_assert(is_nested< type2 >::value, ""); // fail
```

The 4th check will fail because `type2` is just `int`, which is not nested.