# How do I create a type list to expand into a tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to create a class that has a tuple of all the types that are passed to it. I want it to take a type list as a template parameter, and use the classes within that list as the classes an internal tuple will contain. Currently, I have something like this, which doesn't actually compile.

```
template<class ... T>
struct ComponentList {};

template<ComponentList<typename ...T> >
class ComponentManager{
    std::tuple<T...> components;
};
```

The reason I want to have `ComponentList` be its own type is because I want to also pass in other type lists later. Is this possible? If not, what would be an alternative that will work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a template to rebind the parameters from your type-level list into `std::tuple`:

```
template<class A, template<class...> class B>
struct rebind_;

template<template<class...> class A, class... T, template<class...> class B>
struct rebind_<A<T...>, B> {
    using type = B<T...>;
};

template<class A, template<class...> class B>
using rebind = typename rebind_<A, B>::type;
```

Then use it like so:

```
template<class... T>
struct ComponentList {};

template<class List>
struct ComponentManager {
    rebind<List, std::tuple> components;
};

int main() {
    using List = ComponentList<int, char, long>;
    ComponentManager<List> manager;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(manager.components) << '\n';
}
```

I guess if you want to enforce that the original type is `ComponentList`, you can use `enable_if` and [`is_instantiation_of`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251408/246886):

```
template<class List,
    typename = std::enable_if<is_instantiation_of<List, ComponentList>::value>::type>
struct ComponentManager {
    rebind<List, std::tuple> components;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Would you be able to enforce that all your typelist classes provide a `tuple_t` type, with their internal types? Something like:

```
template <class ... T>
struct ComponentList {
    typedef std::tuple<T...> tuple_t;
};

template<class T>
class ComponentManager {
    typename T::tuple_t components;
};
```

Usage is what you'd expect:

```
ComponentManager<ComponentList<int, double> > cm;
```

Comment: This is a possibility, but I was hoping of a nicer solution of both enforcing the type of the provided class to be a `ComponentList` and also to be able to manipulate the types inside the type list (such as instead of making them tuples, maybe make each type be a vector of the type and stick that inside of a tuple).